# Component InvokeAsync Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

We have a cshtml-View that is invoking a ViewComponent like this:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("WetterAPIViewComponent")
```

The ViewComponent itself is defined like that:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "WetterAPIViewComponent")]
public class WetterAPIViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    // ...
}
```

So it has the ViewComponent attribute, is public and non-abstract.

Unfortunately, I still get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A view component named 'WetterAPIViewComponent' could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.'

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: might be farfetched but the error states either the attribute **OR** having it end with ViewComponent, you seem to have both

Comment: I didnt have the ViewComponent attribute at first and it didn't work

Comment: Hi @xeraphim, could not reproduce the same issue as yours. Try to clean and rebuild the project. Be sure all the nuget packages in your project match .net core sdk.

Comment: thank you @Rena, the clean and rebuild actually surprisingly worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code are prettily good working. Try to right-click the project to **Clean and Rebuild** the project.